# Explicit isomorphism between $L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)$ and $L^2(\mathbb{R})$?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, hilbert-spaces, integral-transforms

As Hilbert spaces, $L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)$ and $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ are isomorphic. Of course the isomoprhism is vastly not unique. I wonder if there are any particularly nice explicit isomorphisms. E.g. I wonder if there is an integral transform
$$
f(x,y) \mapsto (K f)(z)=\int dx\, dy K(x,y,z) f(x,y)
$$
with a nice explicit kernel $K(x,y,z)$ which maps $L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)$ isometrically onto $L^2(\mathbb{R})$? Any example would be appreciated.

Comment: You can take an explicit Schauder basis for $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ (*e.g.* Hermite polynomials) and use your favourite explicit enumeration of $\mathbb{N}^2$ to construct a unitary isomorphism using the tensored basis for $L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)$.

Comment: Pullback by the Peano curve gives an isomorphism between $L^2([0,1]^2)$ and $L^2([0,1])$.

Comment: A measure probability algebra is a pair $(A,\mu)$ where $A$ is a $\sigma$-complete Boolean algebra and $\mu(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_{k})=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(a_{k})$ and $\mu(a)=0$ iff $a=0$ and $\mu(1)=1$. Define a metric $d$ on $A$ by letting $d(x,y)=\mu(x\oplus y)$. Caratheodory has proven that all the atomless separable measure probability algebra is isomorphic, and such an isomorphism lifts to an isomorphism between the $L^{2}$-spaces. This is an abstraction of Terry Tao's example. More results like these can be found in Royden's book Real Analysis (3rd edition) Ch. 15.

Comment: @TerryTao My answer is related to yours, but has some additional features.

Comment: In the case where $1\leq p<\infty,p\neq 2$, Banach (Lamperti generalized this result) has shown that the only isometries $U:L^{p}[0,1]\rightarrow L^{p}[0,1]$ (which are not necessarily onto) are the mappings where $Uf=h\cdot(f\circ\phi)$ for some $h\in L^{p}$ and Borel mapping $\phi:[0,1]\rightarrow[0,1]$ (this holds in the real and complex case). Therefore, any isometry of $L^{2}$-spaces that is not of this form must only be an isometry where $p=2$.

Comment: I used your result (Linear extension operators...) in my research years ago in the paper P. Hajłasz, P. Koskela, H. Tuominen, Sobolev embeddings, extensions and measure density condition J. Funct. Anal. 254 (2008), 1217--1234. Actually, the original version of the paper was rejected by Maz'ya, because I was not aware of your result :)

Comment: Thanks all for your comments! Maybe the Peano curve one will be the one which will do the trick for me (since I am looking at a particular application). It's funny because I am currently 10km from Cuneo, Piedmont, Italy where Giuseppe Peano was born and where there is a monument to the Peano curve: http://www.slrobertson.com/galleries/europe/italy/piedmont/scenic/cuneo-peano-curve-monument-2.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following result was obtained by an "explicit" construction in [1]. It is related to the comment of Terry Tao. A modification of the argument allows one to replace the cube by the whole space.

> **Theorem.** If $k\geq n$ and $1\leq p\leq \infty$, then there is an isometric isomorphism $\Phi: L^p([0,1]^k)\to L^p([0,1]^n)$ such that $\Phi(u)$ is continuous on $(0,1)^n$ for each $u\in L^p([0,1]^k)$ that is continuous on $(0,1)^k$.

I do not know if the result is true for $k<n$.

During the editorial corrections one of the results in the paper (the Homeomorphic Measures Theorem) has been stated incorrectly; the erratum is available at https://sites.google.com/view/piotr-hajasz/research/publications?authuser=0

**[1] P. Hajłasz, P. Strzelecki**, How to measure volume with a thread. *Amer. Math. Monthly* 112 (2005), no. 2, 176–179.